# How can my List class contain all types?

Tags: c++, variables, types

This question is part of assignment for my data structures class I'll post part of the description below.

Modify your List class (with the linked list as backend) to support generics so 
that it not only can contain integers, but other types such as floats and 
characters. I have provided a new main function as well as the output 
generated from my implementation. 
Hint: you only need to add one line and change a single word in five lines. So 
this should not take you long.

The problem i'm having is, is understanding the question while it may seem pretty simple to most i might just be over thinking it. It states i only need to add one line and i'm assuming that line would be inserted in the portion of the following code:

```
class List
{
  private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *link;
    };
```

Now i'm unsure of how i'll add this last line but i was thinking maybe i could do:

int, char, float data;

or is that not a valid way of doing so? i'm aware of the 5 places elsewhere in the code i'd need to change things but the question is very confusing to me. Thank you.

Comment: IMO the question and selected answer do not match. Maybe change the question wording? I would vote it down if I could, also because the solution, 'generics', (templates) was in your own problem statement.

Comment: @codah Generics is another file that will go along with this one i'm working on, furthermore before this i wasn't aware that a generic data type could be defined by using template ( i probably worded this all wrong) since i am still in rather low level cs courses. So i apologize for a poorly worded question if it was so.

Comment: @codah perhaps a better way to word it would be "how can i set it so that a variable can contain more than one data type"?

Comment: BreonThibodeaux No need for apologies, just wanted future readers to not be misled. See the comment from juancopanza 'This won't allow a variable to have more than one type'. It will however allow you to 'contain other types' as per your problem description. Maybe "How can my List class contain all types?". Which is a fundamental concept of templates (generics).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

would

```
template <typename T>
class List {
  private:
   struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *link;
   }
}
```

work?

Comment: wait..is template a keyword that includes all data types?

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux that is not simply answered, you must go learn C++ templates.

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux This won't allow a variable to have more than one type, but it will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you Enrico Granata and @juanchopanza, i understand templates better now after a short tutorial, YouTube is a life saver lol.

Answer (score 1):

unions combine different data types in one location.

e.g.

```
union combined_data {
int i;
float f;
};
```

you can either say 
    combined_data.i = 42;

or 
    combined_data.f = 3.14;

A different solution is to use templates. That is: make several classes, out of one definition. They are different in (for example) a type.

```
template<T>
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node *link;
    };
};
```

you can use it as

```
List<int> intlist;
```

or

```
List<float> floatlist;
```

Comment: Thank you that gave me a lot of clarity on the matter and i believe i have my problem solved now.